# jqgrid complex demo not working

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

it is the whole day i am trying to have this example working on my computer:

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

I cannot go to sleep until I have this working successfully, hence I desperately need yur help! Have yo ever use the jqgrid successfully?

This is the code in my HTML file:

```
<table id="list2"> </table>
<div   id="pager2" > </div>
```

The following is the code in my javascript section:

```
var theURL = 'matter_parties_model/<?php echo $matterID;?>';
alert('Donato');

$("#list2").jqGrid({
url:'server.php?q=2',
datatype: "json",
colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
    {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90,editable:true},
    {name:'name',index:'name asc, invdate', width:100},
    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",editable:true,editrules:{number:true}},
    {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",editable:true,editrules:{number:true}},        
    {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
],
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
pager: '#pcelltbl',
sortname: 'id',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "desc",
caption:"Cell Edit Example",
forceFit : true,
cellEdit: true,
cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
afterEditCell: function (id,name,val,iRow,iCol){
    if(name=='invdate') {
        jQuery("#"+iRow+"_invdate","#celltbl").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
    }
},
afterSaveCell : function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
    if(name == 'amount') {
        var taxval = jQuery("#celltbl").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,iCol+1);
        jQuery("#celltbl").jqGrid('setRowData',rowid,{total:parseFloat(val)+parseFloat(taxval)});
    }
    if(name == 'tax') {
        var amtval = jQuery("#celltbl").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,iCol-1);
        jQuery("#celltbl").jqGrid('setRowData',rowid,{total:parseFloat(val)+parseFloat(amtval)});
    }
}});

jQuery("#celltbl").jqGrid('navGrid','#pgwidth',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

and finally this is the code in my php:

```
<?php
include("../../connections/xxxxxxxx");
$page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page
$limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
$sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;
// connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword)
or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("griddemo") or die("Error conecting to db.");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM invheader a, clients b WHERE          a.client_id=b.client_id");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$count = $row['count'];

if( $count >0 ) {
    $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
} else {
    $total_pages = 0;
}
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
$SQL = "SELECT a.id, a.invdate, b.name, a.amount,a.tax,a.total,a.note FROM invheader a,     clients b WHERE a.client_id=b.client_id ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());
$responce = new stdClass();
$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id];
    $responce->rows[$i] ['cell']=array($row[id],$row[invdate],$row[name],$row[amount],$row[tax],$row[total],$row[not e]);
    $i++;
}        
echo json_encode($responce);
?>
```

now the grid is showing the header but not the editable rows. Any idea? I know it is a complex question for this I asked if you have used this example before? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the 'Cell editing' module is enabled? Did you try `celledit.html` from the demo package (http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) with the jqGrid bundled, and with your version of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`?

Comment: dear tmuguet, yes i tried. That example does not even show the table when i try to load it from my localhost!

Comment: Well, I'm not very surprised, it's not the first time I see demos from jqGrid mysteriously not working "out of the box". Sorry I can't help you more, I've never used cell editing...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, i see many issues.

1. replace all occurences of #celltbl to #list2, as your table id is list2.
2. replace all occurences of #pgwidth & #pcelltbl to #pager2, for same reason.
3. put error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); in php processing, as code contains notice errors which will not be compatible with JSON response

You can also debug it using firebug > net > ajax response, if json output is coming or not. Also check jqgrid php wrapper http://www.phpgrid.org as its very handy to use.